# R losing levels when importing csv file

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

I have one data frame with 3686 rows and 34 columns. When I save this data.frame with `write.csv2(data, file = folder/data.csv2)` and than load it into R again with `read.csv2(folder/data.csv2)`, it also has the same number of rows (3686); but, when I ask for the number of species (Factor) with `unique(data$Species)`, the data table in the Environment has 708 Levels and the one I imported showed only 554 Levels.

```
str(imported_dataframe$Species)
```

Output: Factor w/ 554 levels

```
str(Data_in_Environment$Species)
```

Output: Factor w/ 708 levels

Can anyone help me?

Comment: suggestion on improving question - maybe start off by saying you have a data frame environment with 708 levels in it etc. at the beginning and then say how you save this into another file and when you import that file you have lost the data - at least this is what I assume is happening after reading your post several times as it seems hard for me to follow.

Comment: Yes you are right ! Thanks for the advice !

Answer (score 1):

The levels attribute is lost when you write to CSV. You could either export the levels separately and set them in your data.frame.

```
# Species is a factor with three levels
all_levels <- levels(iris$Species)
all_levels
# [1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica" 

# export table where not all levels are present
write.csv2(head(iris), file = "iris_tmp.csv", row.names = FALSE)

# also export complete list of levels
cat(all_levels, file = "iris_levels_tmp.txt")

# import both levels and data
all_levs <- scan("iris_levels_tmp.txt", what = "")
iris6 <- read.csv2("iris_tmp.csv")

# unrepresented levels have been lost
levels(iris6$Species)
# [1] "setosa"

# define Species as factor with all levels
iris6$Species <- factor(iris6$Species, levels = all_levs)
```

Alternatively you could export an R data object using `save`/`load`.

```
iris5 <- head(iris, n = 5)
save("iris5", file = "iris5.rda")
# load back iris5
load(file = "iris5.rda")
levels(iris5$Species)
# [1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It didn´t worked with the script but saveRDS worked ! I am so thankful for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `csvy` library and export csv file with yaml header containing factor levels:

```
# library load
library(csvy)
library(dplyr)

# relevel factos
iris_releveled = iris %>% mutate(Species = relevel(Species, "virginica","setosa","versicolor"))
# write csv file
write.csv2(iris_releveled,"iris_releveled.csv")
# load exported dataset
iris_relevel_loaded = read.csv2("iris_releveled.csv",stringsAsFactors = T)
# now factor levels are lost
iris_relevel_loaded$Species %>% levels()

# write CSVy file from dataset with releveled factors
write_csvy(iris_releveled,  file = "iris_releveled.csvy")
# read csv file with original factor levels
iris_relevel_loaded = read_csvy("iris_releveled.csvy", stringsAsFactors = T)
# now factor levels are kept
iris_relevel_loaded$Species %>% levels()
```